# Excel/VBA: How do I convert a single row into an array of the cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I thought this would be simple, but apparently the geniuses at Microsoft think differently.

I am writing Excel VBA to loop through the rows in an Excel worksheet and for each row (a Range object), I want to extract the cell values as an array. I've done some searching and found some supposed solutions that are not at all intuitive, nor do they work.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

```
Private Sub Separate_By_DC()
    Dim row_ As Range
    Dim row_str As String
    
    For Each row_ In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Row_To_Array(row_)
        Debug.Print UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
        
        ' row_str = Concat_Row(row_)
        ' Debug.Print row_str
    Next row_
End Sub

Private Function Row_To_Array(row_ As Range) As Variant
    Row_To_Array = row_.Value
End Function
```

Comment: `arr = YourRow.Value`? http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I tried to get the length of the array, and it always returns 1. There are 6 columns in each row.

Comment: Did you specify the `,2` second argument of `UBound`?

Comment: `arr` is a 2D array. `Ubound` here returns the number of rows, which is 1 as expected. `Debug.Print Ubound(arr, 2) - Lbound(arr, 2) + 1`?

Comment: OK, so the second argument is the dimension index?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)

Comment: `Row_To_Array = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(row_.Value))` will give you a zero-based array when `row_` is horizontal

Comment: @Tim Williams: You mean (1D) one-based array i.e. an `Application.Transpose` will always result in a one-based array. In this case, a 'double transpose' for a one-row range will result in a 1D array, while for a one-column range, it would result in a 2D array (the same as before the 'double transpose', the `LBound` and `UBound` for the 2nd dimension being 1), making it redundant. In general, after transposing (single, double...) a range, if the result is one row, the array will be 1D otherwise it will be 2D (one-based in any case).

Comment: @VBasic2008 - well I did *mean* zero-based, but you are right, it's actually 1-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the most easiest way would be:

```
Sub test()

Dim mArr As Variant
Dim i As Long

mArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A10")) 'Transpoose to make the array one dimensional

'loop through the array
For i = LBound(mArr, 1) To UBound(mArr, 1) 'For one dimensional you can remove ",1"
    'do something with mArr value
    Cells(i, "C").Value = mArr(i) 'Print the array value
Next i

End Sub
```

---

For 2 dimensional array you can loop through it by state the dimensional index:

```
Dim mArr As Variant
Dim i As Long

mArr = Range("A1:A10") 'Use 2 dimension

'loop through the array
For i = LBound(mArr, 1) To UBound(mArr, 1)
    'do something with mArr value
    Cells(i, "C").Value = mArr(i, 1)
Next i
```

Comment: Yeah, that was one I found, but when I attempted to use `Application.Transpose`, I got an error.

Comment: OK, not sure what I did wrong the first time, but now that seems to work.

Comment: @JosephGagnon be aware that Application.Transpose has a size limit.  It may have failed because the data is too large to transpose that way.  If so, store it as a vertical 2D array Create a 1D array that has the same number of items as the number of rows.  Iterate the first array and put it in the second.  Or just use the 2D array and forget transposing.